# PINE-SCRIPT: Creating a Histogram Average - 24 Day Lookback

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am using the hist to represent the histogram data based on the MACD indicator.

I am trying to create a buy signal whereby the buy would be placed when the histogram is a positive number that is greater than the average of the past 24 days previous histogram data.

However, histogram data can be positive or negative, the number, whether positive or negative, doesn't matter, but I can't find a better solution than this, but there has to be.

Currently I am taking the multiple of the hist * hist / 2 for every day then dividing the whole. This seems clunky and unnecessary but I don't know another way to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    hist         = macdDaily - signalDaily

    histGreater24 = hist[0] >   ((((hist[1]  * hist[1])  / 2) + ((hist[2]  * hist[2])  / 2) + ((hist[3]  * hist[3])  / 2) + ((hist[4]  * hist[4])  / 2) + ((hist[5]  * hist[5])  / 2) + ((hist[6]  * hist[6])  / 2) + ((hist[7]  * hist[7])  / 2) + ((hist[8]  * hist[8])  / 2) + ((hist[9]  * hist[9])  / 2) + ((hist[10] * hist[10]) / 2) + ((hist[11] * hist[11]) / 2) + ((hist[12] * hist[12]) / 2) + ((hist[13] * hist[13]) / 2) + ((hist[14] * hist[14]) / 2) + ((hist[15] * hist[15]) / 2) + ((hist[16] * hist[16]) / 2) + ((hist[17] * hist[17]) / 2) + ((hist[18] * hist[18]) / 2) + ((hist[19] * hist[19]) / 2) + ((hist[20] * hist[20]) / 2) + ((hist[21] * hist[21]) / 2) + ((hist[22] * hist[22]) / 2) + ((hist[23] * hist[23]) / 2) + ((hist[24] * hist[24]) / 2)) / 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `sma(source,length)` function will calculate the average of the last 'n' bars.

use the `sma()` function in place of the code you are using , it will perform the same function as you want

```
histGreater24 =hist>sma((hist*hist)/2,24)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use security() to get data from the higher timeframe (Daily) to calculate the average of hist or you can use different sources such as `hl2 hlc3 ohlc4`. (V5) Try this code ->

```
htf_src            = math.avg(number0 = ta.highest(source = hist, length = 1), number1 = ta.lowest(source = hist, length = 1))

f_security(_symbol, _tf, _src) => request.security(symbol = _symbol, timeframe = _tf, expression = _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0]) 

htf_source         = f_security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", htf_src) // Here the expression hist could be replaced by hl2 hlc3 ohlc4 or any source you want to get from the "D" - Daily timeframe

condition_1        = hist[1] > 0 
condition_2        = hist[1] > htf_source

signal_condition    = condition_1 and condition_2 

plotchar(
 series     = signal_condition,
 title      = "HIST Condition",
 char       = "☀",
 location   = location.abovebar,
 color      = color.new(color = color.lime, transp = 0),
 size       = size.normal
 )

// # ========================================================================= #
// *   # The opposite condition  
// *   > 
// *   > condition_3 = hist[1] < 0
// *   > signal_bottom_condition = condition_3 and not condition_2 
// *   > plotchar(series = signal_bottom_condition, "Hist Down Conditoin", char = "*", location = location.abovebar, color = color.new(color = color.red, transp = 0), size = size.normal)
// # ========================================================================= #
```